# CORS Issue with Angular MSAL Azure AD Dotnet Core Web API

Tags: .net, angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have been working through this tutorial:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi

The Authentication works fine.

However, I get a CORS exception in the console:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44351/api/todolist/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

In startup.cs I changed:

// builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
//        .AllowAnyMethod()
//        .AllowAnyHeader();

to:

builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowCredentials();

This had no effect.

Can anyone help me to resolve please?

Here is the startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration);

        // Creating policies that wraps the authorization requirements
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share whole code about cors in your core api ?

Comment: In newer versions of Chrome, you might see an CORS error in the developer console when actually there was an Internal Server Error in the backend. Check for exceptions in the logs there.

Comment: I've added the startup.cs to the question (above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all the methods you tried, as well as other methods, and encountered the same problem in this project. More details can be found in the official documentation. According to the instructions in the official documentation, the cross-domain solutions you tried before are all achievable, and I think the problem may appear in this sample project. If you re-create the demo, there will be no such problems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In the end, the suggestion I gave was to set up `CORS` on the portal, and I personally tested it to solve this problem.

In addition, if you need to trace the root of the problem, it is recommended to use the packet capture method for analysis, check the request header of the two websites, you can refer to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross%20-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services%20#%20enabling-cors-for-azure-storage) .

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the CORS issue with the code sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi

I made the following change to Startup.cs:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
 {
   // builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
   //        .AllowAnyMethod()
   //        .AllowAnyHeader();

   builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowCredentials()
             .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
   }));
```

And this resolved the CORS issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**.Net Core Framework 6.0**

In Program.cs file

Add the following code sample before application build call `var app = builder.Build();`

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("angular-app", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    });
});
```

Allow any method, headers and credentials by preceding `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")` with the following

```
.AllowAnyMedthod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowCredentials()
```

After application build call, add the following line after the if statement that checks whether the app environment is in dev mode

```
app.UseCors("angular-app");
```

[image]