# Why does MSAL.js return CORS header is missing

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, msal.js

MSAL.js keeps returning the following errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/order. (Reason:
> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/order. (Reason:
> CORS request did not succeed).

My Back-end is hosted in Azure and is also registered as a Web API in Azure Active Directory.

The Front-end has a proxy.conf.json and is registered in Azure Active Directory.

I successfully authenticate and receive ID and Access Tokens, when I try to access API (which require authentication, I receive these errors).

My **proxy.conf.json** looks like:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://webapi.azurewebsites.net",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your .NET Core web API hosted on the same Azure Web App Service as your Angular site?  Might be helpful to describe what parts are hosted on what cloud appliance.

Comment: My first thought is that you need to add an [Authorization Header](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers), but it could be several other things as well.

Comment: The Web API and Web App are hosted separately on Azure. I added the authorization headers too.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your server-side ? https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript.md

Comment: Similar question may answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977557/cors-issue-with-angular-msal-azure-ad-dotnet-core-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an access_as_user scope (api://[Application (client) ID]/access_as_user) and set it in the ProtectedResource in the SPA - Client App

```
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap
    .set(auth.resources.graphApi.resourceUri, auth.resources.graphApi.resourceScopes)
    .set(auth.resources.Api.resourceUri, auth.resources.Api.resourceScopes);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: [...auth.resources.Api.resourceScopes]
    }
  };
}
```

Simply create a json file in the app-folder and Add import line in your app.module to access the json file

```
import * as auth from '../app/auth-config.json';
```

The content of auth json file looks similar to:

```
"resources": {
      "graphApi": {
        "resourceUri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users",
        "resourceScopes": [ "User.Read", "openid", "profile" ]
      },
      "Api": {
        "resourceUri": "https://webapi.azurewebsites.net",
        "resourceScopes": [ "api://[Application (client) ID]/User.Read",
                            "api://[Application (client) ID]/access_as_user" ]
      }
    }
```